# Run custom external command from scala

Tags: bash, scala, scripting, path, torch

I am trying to integrate [torch](http://torch.ch/), with scala.

I have following bash script (foo.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo hello world
th *rest of command*
```

and I try to execute it in scala to get some output:

```
"./foo.sh" !!
```

However it gives me an error:

> line 42: th: command not found

Is there any workaround to get this working?

Comment: I sugget to add full path to `th`.

Comment: @Cyrus holy molly, I spent too much time to get this working. If you post this as an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sugget to add full path to `th`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have torch installed?
If yes, try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/.profile
source ~/.bashrc
echo hello world
th *rest of command*
```

or better run `th` with full path. Full path can be obtain by command:

```
type th
```